# Dropwizard metric to send Gauge : Error: Override is not allowed when implementing an interface method

Tags: java, metrics

I'm trying the Dropwizard metrics as specified in their website. Below is the code:

```
public class QueueManager {
    private final Queue queue;

    public QueueManager(MetricRegistry metrics, String name) {
        this.queue = new Queue();
        metrics.register(MetricRegistry.name(QueueManager.class, name, "size"),
                         new Gauge<Integer>() {
                             @Override
                             public Integer getValue() {
                                 return queue.size();
                             }
                         });
    }
}
```

Question:

1. I see an error in my IDE indicating "Override is not allowed when implementing an interface method." as Gauge is one of the interfaces.
2. When I run the code without `@Override` keyword, the program continues but, the `getValue()` code block is not executed.